# Express Req.body empty on one PC but works fine on another

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-hosting

I've a Firebase Express JS project folder on 1 PC.
When I run firebase serve, everything works fine.

I am trying to change my work PC to another one.
I've setup my nodejs, firebase cli, and opened the same exact folder on this new PC (via OneDrive with all files made available locally)

However, when I run firebase serve and attempt to POST, I see that the req.body is empty.

Am I missing something here?

---

The debug log of the working PC shows

```
[debug] [2020-12-19T09:39:00.832Z] Accepted request POST /project_path/sessionLogin --> app_name
```

While the debug log of the non working PC shows

```
[debug] [2020-12-19T09:34:13.542Z] <<< [apiv2][status] POST http://localhost:5001/project_path/sessionLogin 500
[debug] [2020-12-19T09:34:13.542Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST http://localhost:5001/project_path/sessionLogin [stream]
[info] i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2020:09:34:13 +0000] "POST /sessionLogin HTTP/1.1" 500 2257 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"hosting"},"message":"127.0.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2020:09:34:13 +0000] \"POST /sessionLogin HTTP/1.1\" 500 2257 \"http://localhost:5000/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36\""}}
[info] >  TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined {"user":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"}}
[info] >      at C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\index.js:4059:38 {"user":"    at C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\index.js:4059:38","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\index.js:4059:38"}}
[info] >      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) {"user":"    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)"}}
[info] >      at next (C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13) {"user":"    at next (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:137:13)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at next (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:137:13)"}}
[info] >      at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3) {"user":"    at Route.dispatch (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:112:3)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at Route.dispatch (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:112:3)"}}
[info] >      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) {"user":"    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)"}}
[info] >      at C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22 {"user":"    at C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:281:22","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:281:22"}}
[info] >      at Function.process_params (C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12) {"user":"    at Function.process_params (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:335:12)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at Function.process_params (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:335:12)"}}
[info] >      at next (C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10) {"user":"    at next (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:275:10)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at next (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:275:10)"}}
[info] >      at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:100:7) {"user":"    at urlencodedParser (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\body-parser\\lib\\types\\urlencoded.js:100:7)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at urlencodedParser (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\body-parser\\lib\\types\\urlencoded.js:100:7)"}}
[info] >      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) {"user":"    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)"}}
[info] >      at trim_prefix (C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13) {"user":"    at trim_prefix (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:317:13)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at trim_prefix (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:317:13)"}}
[info] >      at C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7 {"user":"    at C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:284:7","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:284:7"}}
[info] >      at Function.process_params (C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12) {"user":"    at Function.process_params (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:335:12)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at Function.process_params (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:335:12)"}}
[info] >      at next (C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10) {"user":"    at next (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:275:10)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at next (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:275:10)"}}
[info] >      at jsonParser (C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:119:7) {"user":"    at jsonParser (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\body-parser\\lib\\types\\json.js:119:7)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at jsonParser (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\body-parser\\lib\\types\\json.js:119:7)"}}
[info] >      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\name\firebase_files\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) {"user":"    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\\Users\\name\\firebase_files\\functions\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)"}}
[info] i  functions: Finished "app_name" in ~1s {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"app_name"},"message":"Finished \"app_name\" in ~1s"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run `npm install` to be sure all packages are installed correctly. Is there no error message in your console?

Comment: I've tried that, however it wasn't working either.

Yes, there's error in the console, which I've added it into my question.

Comment: Honestly it can be a lot of things. I would like to help you if you want to. Can you please provide some more code, like the endpoint you are calling? Are other POST endpoints working or returning undefined as well?